# Lavavel syntax error - unexpected '}'

Tags: php, laravel

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out.  I'm trying to load a form in my route in Laravel and I keep getting this error ..

```
FatalErrorException syntax error, unexpected '}'
```

// My route...

```
Route::get('/signup', function()
 {
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
    //
    {{ Form::close() }}
 });
```

This should work out of the box. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those `{{ }}` sections look like they belong in a template somewhere, definitely not in the PHP. Haven't used Laravel though so hard to know exactly where they should be.

Comment: `{{...}}` is `Blade` [template](http://laravel.com/docs/templates) syntax and belongs to only a `viewname.blade.php` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `{{...}}` in wrong place, this is `Blade` template syntax and should not be used in your route's handler, instead create a `view` file and load that view from your `route` or from a `class`, you may try something like this:

```
Route::get('/signup', function()
{
    return View::make('signup');
});
```

Next, create a view in your `app/views` directory and use `signup.blade.php` as the name, for example:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
        {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username')) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

Make sure you have a `views/layouts/master.blade.php` file available.

Comment: Welcome, read the [manual](http://laravel.com/docs/templates) properly, it' very basic of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

The routes.php file is not a blade templating system so you don't have to add those curly braces to echo your function(s).

Try this:

```
Route::get('/signup', function()
 {
    Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar'));
    //
    Form::close();
 });
```

Comment: getting syntax error, unexpected ';'  and tried removing ";" and I get syntax error, unexpected 'Form' (T_STRING)

Comment: @btaylor507 Line 3 is missing a closing `)`.

Comment: thanks marty, still not getting any output. Blank screen now with empty source. err this is frustrating. Feel embarrassed right now. lol

Comment: Thanks Cosmin too. I feel like I'm wasting your time though. I think I need to hit the textbook again.